# Ofstream create a file in Windows temp directory

Tags: c++, windows, ofstream, temp

```
ofstream batch;
batch.open("olustur.bat", ios::out);
batch <<"@echo off\n";
batch.close();
system("olustur.bat");
```

I want to create olustur.bat inside the Windows temp folder. I couldn't manage to achieve it. I am new to C++ so is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Normally in `C:\users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp`

Comment: Yes but this will only work for my computer.

Comment: Temp is also stored in `%TEMP%`. Depending on how you're compiling your C++, you can use `std::getenv` or `GetEnvironmentVariable`.

Comment: %TEMP%\olustur.bat isn'tt working either

Comment: You can't use `%TEMP%` with `ofstream` directly (or any other file I/O function, for that matter). You have to query its value first. Use `std::getenv("TEMP")` or `GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP")` to get the resolved temp path, then append your filename to the end of that path, and then pass that complete path to `ofstream`.  .

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Win32 API [`GetTempPath()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364992.aspx) function to retrieve the full path  of the temp folder, then use `std::ofstream` to write files to it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    CHAR czTempPath[MAX_PATH] = {0};
    GetTempPathA(MAX_PATH, czTempPath); // retrieving temp path
    cout << czTempPath << endl;

    string sPath = czTempPath;
    sPath += "olustur.bat"; // adding my file.bat

    ofstream batch;
    batch.open(sPath.c_str());
    batch << "@echo off\n";
    batch.close();

    system(sPath.c_str());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually my problem is getting it to here 'batch.open("olustur.bat", ios::out);'

Comment: @RıdvanÇetin Sounds like you need to learn how out concatenate strings.